# Binding Collectionviewsource with WPF Datagrid and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

I'm relatively new at WPF and C#.  Following this [example](http://chateau-logic.com/content/wpf-entity-framework-listbox-datagrid-filtering-using-collectionviewsource-collectionview), I have created a form with a datagrid and two comboboxes (FileName and PartID) that I'd like to use to filter the datagrid (surveyresponsesDataGrid).

Here is my XAML for the WPF Form:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    Title="Review Data" Height="446" Width="987" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SWA_IFR" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        Source="{Binding ElementName=surveyresponses, Path=FileName.SelectedItem}" 
        x:Key="cvs" Filter="fn_Filter" 
        x:Name="srView"
        CollectionViewType="{x:Type dat:ListCollectionView}" />
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="247" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" Margin="12,93,0,0" Name="surveyresponsesDataGrid" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="941">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fileUploadNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=FileUploadName}" Header="File Upload Name" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="participantIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ParticipantID}" Header="Participant ID" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="quesIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=QuesID}" Header="Ques ID" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="quesTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=QuesType}" Header="Ques Type" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scoreIntColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ScoreInt}" Header="Score Int" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scoreTextColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ScoreText}" Header="Score Text" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scoreDescrColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ScoreDescr}" Header="Score Descr" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ComboBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,17,0,0" Name="FileName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" SelectionChanged="FileName_SelectionChanged" />
    <Label Content="Filter by File Upload Name" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,17,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" />
    <ComboBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,52,0,0" Name="PartID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211"  />
    <Label Content="Filter by Participant ID" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,52,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" />
</Grid>
```

Here is my code:

> public partial class ReviewData : Window
>
> ```
> {
>     SMEntities context = new SMEntities();
>
>     public ReviewData()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>
>     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         var filename = context.surveyresponses.Select(f => f.FileUploadName).Distinct();
>         this.FileName.ItemsSource = filename;
>
>         var partid = context.surveyresponses.Select(p => p.ParticipantID).Distinct();
>         this.PartID.ItemsSource = partid;
>
>     }
>
>     void fn_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.Item is surveyresponse)
>             e.Accepted = (e.Item as surveyresponse).FileUploadName.ToUpper().Contains(FileName.Text.ToUpper());
>         else
>             e.Accepted = true;
>     }
>
>     private void RefreshList()
>     {
>         if (surveyresponsesDataGrid.Items is CollectionView)
>         {
>             CollectionViewSource csv = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("cvs");
>             if (csv != null)
>                 csv.View.Refresh();
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void srFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         RefreshList();
>     }
> } }
> ```

First problem is that I don't think the CollectionViewSource is correctly setup in the Window.Resource section, but I can't find any clear guidance about what's off.  The EF class is surveyresponses but not sure that the I've correctly set the Path attribute -- currently it is set to the SelectedItem of the first combobox FileName.  My goal is to filter the datagrid for only the entries that match the selection in the FileName combobox.

Second problem is that I'm uncertain how I would go about having a secondary filter, such that once the first filter is set, that selecting the PartId combobox will further filter the datagrid based on the second field (Participant ID).

I'm missing something fundamental and don't see what it is.

Thanks for the guidance.